# Plotting Deedle frame

Tags: lambda, f#, key-value, deedle

I have the following piece of code:

```
let mychart = frame.GetAllSeries() |> Seq.iter(fun key value -> Chart.Line(value, Name=key) |> Chart.Combine
```

where `frame.GetAllSeries()` returns a `seq<KeyValuePair>`. I'd like to pipe the sequence directly in a chart.
I thought I could iterate through the sequence. The problem is that I can't find an idomatic way to access the key and value separately that could be plugged in directly in the lambda expression.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This works:

```
let chart = frame.GetAllSeries() |> Seq.map( fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> Chart.Line(v |> Series.observations, Name=k)) |> Chart.Combine
```

.. could it get simpler? I have a large dataset and I am afraid the performance gets impacted by so many transformations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "convert" a Dictionary into a sequence in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117302/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-sequence-in-f)

Comment: Fixed the bug, but I now have a thick expression. I changed the title to focus on this specific issue, hoping for help to simplify the line of code above.

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis I assume `frame.GetAllSeries()` uses dictionary/map internally. Why can't it return sequence of tuples (with e.g. `Map.toSeq`)?

Comment: @Eugene: Unfortunately, I am not a contributor of Deedle ([link](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/)). I also fail to understand how a seq of tuples would help..

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis I didn't see your update. With tuples you can write
`let mychart = frame.GetAllSeries() |> Seq.map(fun (k, v) -> Chart.Line(value, Name=key) |> Chart.Combine`
But it isn't much simpler than `KeyValue` variant.

Comment: @Eugene: I see. Yes, it is not much simpler than the original variant. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already figured out, using `Series.observations` gives you a sequence of key-value pairs from the series that you can then pass to `Chart.Line` etc.

This is definitely something that should not be needed and you can make the code simpler using extension method that lets you automatically plot a series:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module FsLabExtensions =
  type FSharp.Charting.Chart with
    static member Line(data:Series<'K, 'V>, ?Name, ?Title, ?Labels, ?Color, ?XTitle, ?YTitle) =
      Chart.Line(Series.observations data, ?Name=Name, ?Title=Title, ?Labels=Labels, ?Color=Color, ?XTitle=XTitle, ?YTitle=YTitle)
```

If you include this, you can plot series directly:

```
let s = series [ for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 1.0 -> x, sin x ]
Chart.Line(s)
```

You can also reference Deedle & F# Charting through our experimental package "FsLab" that includes these overloads (see [here](https://github.com/tpetricek/FsLab/blob/master/FsLab.fsx))